# designing menu with links having round corner underline?

Tags: css

hello every one I have a question, how can I get the code to design a menu like google website with links in the menu have round end underline with less width than the link text. if you look at the picture attached you understand what I mean, thanks very much.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1cq7.png)

here is the link to live website
[click here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/reference)

Comment: Shows what you tried. Also, take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done somewhat with `after` pseudo-selector:

```css
#test{
  background-color:red;
  width:100px;
  margin:0;
  height:50px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

#test:after{
  content: "";
  height: 6px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: blue;
  position:absolute;
  left: 28px;
  top:52px;
  border-top-left-radius:10px;
  border-top-right-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">Link</div>
```